# Declaration of Instance Variables wrong?

Tags: objective-c

My instance variable secondNumber is not declaring itself. Why not?
  (I am new to programming, so please bear with me.)
  In Xcode the error says, "Parse Issue: Expected ';' at the end of declaration list.

```
//  main.m
//  Subtraction
//
//  Copyright 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NumberSub: NSObject

{
int firstNumber
int secondNumber
int result 
}
-(void) print;
-(void) setFirstNumber: (int) f;
-(void) setSecondNumber: (int) s;
-(void) resetAll;
-(void) printResult;
@end

@implementation NumberSub

-(void) setFirstNumber: (int) f;
{
firstNumber = f;
}

-(void) setSecondNumber: (int) s
{ 
secondNumber = s;
}

-(void) print
{
NSLog(@"%i - %i = ", firstNumber, secondNumber);

}

-(void) printResult
{
NSLog(@"%i", firstNumber - secondNumber);
}

-(void) resetAll
{
firstNumber = 0;
secondNumber = 0;
}

@end

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
NumberSub *subtractNumber = [[NumberSub = alloc]init];



[subtractNumber setFirstNumber: 10];
[subtractNumber setSecondNumber: 5];

[subtractNumber print];
[subtractNumber printResult];

[subtractNumber release];   
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Parse Issue: Expected ';' at the end of declaration list." is a pretty clear statement ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the ; at the end of each lines

```
@interface NumberSub: NSObject

{
    int firstNumber;
    int secondNumber;
    int result ;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer by click on the small check sign :)